# Copying an array of generic type

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to rewrite the `ArrayList` class as a custom class.
I tried doing this without using ANY java built in functions and just using basic capabilities of the java.
I wrote this part of code for the `MyArrayList.toArray` method:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    E[] array = (E[]) new Object[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        array[i] = data[i];
    }
    return array;
}
```

But as you may know, it throws a `ArrayStoreException`. 
Then I took a look at the *OpenJDK6* implementation of ArrayList class and there was usage of `Arrays.copyOf();` and `System.arraycopy();` which is not what I want.

Can anyone help me write this method, ONLY using java native capabilities?

Comment: just look at the source of those methods

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? As @NimChimpsky said, you should just have a look at the source code of these methods in the JDK...

Comment: I have an array of a generic type, half of the array is filled. I want to return the filled part of the array as an array of objects.

Comment: As @Makoto said, sources are using C written program to provide a safe copy.
Tnx all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to circumvent the `ArrayStoreException` in vanilla Java, as that's there to prevent the programmer from placing something into an array that just can't be placed into an array.

[Recall from the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#d5e13546) that this is being checked and enforced at runtime.  Since [generic types aren't reifiable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7), the JVM is explicitly forbidding the array creation.

> If the type of the value being assigned is not assignment-compatible (§5.2) with the component type, an `ArrayStoreException` is thrown.
>
> If the component type of an array were not reifiable (§4.7), the Java Virtual Machine could not perform the store check described in the preceding paragraph. This is why an array creation expression with a non-reifiable element type is forbidden (§15.10). One may declare a variable of an array type whose element type is non-reifiable, but assignment of the result of an array creation expression to the variable will necessarily cause an unchecked warning (§5.1.9).

[`System#arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) gets around this by cheating, a little bit.

- It's a **native** method, meaning there's no implementation in pure Java; it's written in C instead.
- It only throws an `ArrayStoreException` if the primitive components of the arrays don't match, or you're mixing primitive component arrays and reference component arrays.